# What's the acceptance of rational trigonometry in current mathematics courses?

Tags: trigonometry, education

I've been reading about [Wildberger's rational trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Proportions:_Rational_Trigonometry_to_Universal_Geometry) and I'm willing to learn it. I'm wondering if it's usage is accepted in undergraduate mathematics courses. It seems there's a redefinition on some concepts of trigonometry which may impact some expected results. So, is it currently accepted in mathematics undergraduate courses or it's still only a proposal with some benefit?

Comment: It is just the same thing but making emphasis in getting formulas written in terms of that **quadrance** and **spread**. Of course, it is fine. The only problem is that it will be your task to translate back and forth for the people asking you about **distance** and **angles** and giving you data about distances and angles.

Comment: Based on the little I know of rational trigonometry you would have a hard time communicating with others. However learning "alternative" an formulation might give you a different perspective which might be good. At the end of the day make sure you take a standard trig course since there is a lot of value in the traditional approach.

Comment: @RGB I'm curious, in rational trigonometry do students study sine and cosine waves? It seems like a difficult concept to study if the concept of an angle is replaced with spread.

Comment: Sine is just the square root of the **spread**. It is just a different language. You just need to translate.

Comment: @Spencer [Look here](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~norman/papers/TrigComparison.pdf).

Comment: I've seen the identity with sine and spread before in a youtube video a long time ago. My question wasn't so much "how do you talk about the function sin(x) without angles?" but "how is the study of periodic wave behavior affected by a lack of angles?". The reason I ask this is because it seems like rational trigonometry (once again I've only seen one video and the information Gustavo linked me to) is concerned mostly with geometric questions, but I feel a lot of the utility of trigonometry comes from abstracting away from the original geometric concepts. That said, thanks for your responses.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Thank you, most interesting comparison. Have you asked your professors what they think of RT?